# Can real particles become virtual?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, virtual-particles, casimir-effect

I know that [virtual particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_particle) can become real for example with the dynamic Casimir Effect.
But is the opposite also possible? I.e. can real particles become virtual?

Comment: Please see [Virtual Particles: What are they?](https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/virtual-particles-what-are-they/) by Professor Matt Strassler.

Comment: Particles, properly speaking, are not a physical concept as far as relativistic QM goes; thats the real meaning of virtuality.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not really about physics, even though it uses the language of physics ...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in a sense. Virtual particles are a shared fiction: a pictorial summary of mathematical book-keeping for intermediate states in perturbation theory. In Feynman diagram language, they are the "internal lines". Technically, they fail the dispersion relation, the energy-momentum constraints characterizing the real particle they shadow. So real particles and virtual particles turn into each other with the emission or absorption of energy and momentum, in general; this is often effected by a photon, but not always.

But they are always just a metaphor summarizing a mathematical expression for the convenience of the user. A real neutral pion may (arguably; a horrid non-standard picture!) emit a photon, and turn to a virtual pion; which then emits another photon to turn into a real pion. At the end of the day, this amounts to a real pion transmuting to two real photons. (And  experts normally  consider a quark inside a pion undergoing this, instead, in a "triangle diagram".)

A real electron-positron pair in an accelerator collision turns into a virtual photon, which promptly decays/resolves to real particles (J/ψ s, or virtual such), which decay to other real decay products. And on it goes. After a while, the metaphor takes over and calculators automatically take note of energy and momentum on-shell constraints only in specific steps of their estimate.

And so it goes.

Comment: Particles, properly speaking, are not a physical concept as far as relativistic QM goes; thats the real meaning of virtuality.

Comment: It is clear that virtual particles can be viewed as existing at the instant of interaction. For example, the Compton scattering is mediated by a virtual electron. In other words, a real electron absorbs a photon and becomes virtual, then emits a photon and becomes real again. However, I don’t think this is what the question is. The OP seems to be asking if real particles can become virtual forever. If so, then no, virtual particles don’t live forever. The question is also wrong. “Existing” virtual particles cannot become real, because they don’t exist outside of the instant of interaction.

Comment: @safesphere I didn't see any confusions on  times of interaction, forevers, and such, in the question: In covariant perturbation theory these are all fraught terms asking for trouble. I only used s-channel and "time" in the description for ease of visualization, but t-channel stuff could serve as well. My sense is to drive home the metaphor aspect of the concept, and prevent labored phantasies when it is the math that does the driving, after all...

Comment: I did not criticize your answer - I criticized the question +1